# Atom editor root certificate database cannot be managed - SSL verification issue

Tags: database, ssl, certificate, editor, atom-editor

I liked the Atom editor a lot. However, my company cannot approve it because the root certificate database cannot be managed and this compromises SSL verification process. I am not a security expert. So, I don't know what SSL verification process they talk about, and I don't know the root certificate database inside Atom.

As a comparison, NotePad++ and VisualStudioCode are approved in my company.

I wish developers in the Atom team can understand these issues and develop a solution. What do you think? Can this be done?

Comment: As this is about software and software installation, not writing code/software, I'd suggest you ask this question at https://superuser.com/

Comment: If you want to address the Atom developers, you should probably try https://github.com/atom/atom - another place to take this question might be https://discuss.atom.io